# How to access Docker application from browser?

Tags: java, docker, tomcat

I installed docker in RedHat8 and pull the centos8 image and create a container with port 8080 Shown Below.

[image]

In that container, I  installed java and tomcat, and I deployed my wars in tomcat at webapps location and started tomcat the tomcat ran successfully. I gave 80 port (changed in server.xml)  to tomcat to access the application from the browser. After that, I tried to access my application with Url:

> https://40.6.254.159:8080/    (IP address was RedHat server IP)

But I am not able to access the application. Please let me know how to access web application

Comment: Your container has mapped the ports `8080:8080`, which means no access to/from port 80, even if the application that runs in the container allows that traffic. Start the container with a different mapping…

Comment: Read the [documentation of docker](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/).

Comment: please let me know how to give port 80 access to the container

Comment: Start the container with the flag `-p 8080:80`, for example…

Comment: ok How to access the port from the browser

Comment: I added ports it shows like this 8080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8091->80/tcp, :::8091->80/tcp

Comment: Well, then try to access the application at port 8091

Comment: I tried to access it with http://hostip:8091  but it shows This site can’t be reached (and redirected to https://hostip). Please let me know how to solve this issue

Comment: anyone, Please solve this issue

Comment: Have you tried to (1) stop your container and (2) start it again with the most obvious mapping: `-p 80:80`? Then (3), the application *should* be available at `http://red-hat-server-ip/` (no port, you can explicitly pass `:80`).

Comment: Actually, i created Container with 8091:80, So I want to access it with HTTP://hostip:8091

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to stop the container, and run your container with

```
docker run --name rajesh --publish 8080:8080 <other arguments> centos
```

Comment: my tomcat port must be 80, I don't want to change the server.xml